# alternating sign binary representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary, number-systems

91<sub>10</sub> = 1011011<sub>2</sub> = 2⁶+2⁴+2³+2¹+2⁰  = 2⁷-2⁶+2⁵-2³+2²-2⁰
How is called this binary representation where sign is alternating? For all natural numbers this representation is unique. Which are its main properties? Some references?
The way to obtain this representation from usual binary representation is simple:
   1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0<sub>2</sub> (twice 91<sub>10</sub>)
 - 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1<sub>2</sub> (          91<sub>10</sub>) 
__________________
   1-1 1 0-1 1 0-1  (          91<sub>10</sub>)

Comment: I'm not sure this has a name. But, it codes numbers using the runs of 1s in the base-2 representation. Basically because a long run of 1s results in a difference of two powers of $2$. For example $111110011111_2=(2^{12}-2^7)+(2^5-2^0)$ because there are runs of five consecutive $1$s starting at positions $0$ and $7$. I vaguely recall having seen variants of square-and-multiple algorithm (or was it double-and-add?), where the idea was to exploit such patterns. Not sure if those ideas paid any dividends when the binary has a high entropy.

Comment: This looks at first like negabinary representation, but it is something different. In effect the place value of each digit depends on how many 1s are to the left of it.

Comment: Thanks! 'negabinary representation' carries me to 'http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negabinary.html' and this one to https://oeis.org/A039724. In this page a reference is  'Vladimir Shevelev, Two analogs of Thue-Morse sequence, arXiv:1603.04434 [math.NT], 2016.' One of the analogs is the representation that I asked. Properties are shown by Shevelev (May 18 2017) at https://oeis.org/A268411. This representation is called 'balanced binary representation'.